# Call route in p-steps PrimeNG (angular 4)

Tags: angular, primeng

I am new in PrimeNG and facing a problem using p-steps.

I have a stepper menu (3 steps). I want to call steps one by one (a step depends on it's previous step).

I already have different menus for those three steps. In my stepper menu I want to call those routes one by one (according to steps).

I already try **routerLink** of MenuModel API. But routerLink call its own menu instead of loading into Stepper menu.

In MenuModel API i unable to find any other suitable property.

Below is my Code :

HTML :

```
 <p-steps [model]="steps" [(activeIndex)]="this._globals.activeIndex" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>

 <div *ngIf="this._globals.activeIndex == 0">
      <app-order-maint></app-order-maint>
 </div>
```

TS :

```
   this.steps = [{
        label: 'Order',
        command: (event: any) => {

        },
        routerLink: ['/order-maint/order-maint.component']
    },
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Plunker would help